# How to refer to a specific point in Chart Windows Form Control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, microsoft-chart-controls

I am trying to get one point of a Chart in C# Visual Studio 2010 using the following code:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.Item[1]
```

but I get the following error:

> Error 1   'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointCollection'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method
>   'Item' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointCollection'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

But supposedly `Points` being a `DataPointCollection` should have the property `Item` as is shown on Microsoft's webpage:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection.aspx

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely, since Points is the collection, you should be doing:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points[1].Item
```

Comment: actually I fixed it with: `chart1.Series[0].Points[1].YValues` as I can't get it to recognize the `Item`